# Spree cart link not showing in views that wont belong to the Spree Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to show the Spree cart and orders in ALL of my parent Rails views.

The problem is, the cart wont show if it doesn't belong to the Spree engine.

I've seen where the problem comes from:

```
Spree.fetch_cart = ->
  $.ajax
    url: Spree.pathFor("shop/cart_link"),
    success: (data) ->
      $('#link-to-cart').html data
```

I can't access that URL from outside spree...

## Edit: The problem

Its not making the AJAX call when Im outside a Spree View

```
<script>Spree.fetch_cart()</script>
```

Comment: if you want this functionality in all pages then you would probably want your new controllers to actually be part of Spree engine?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but thought I might as well answer in case anyone else is looking for a solution. Just add these two lines to your application's application.js file:

```
//= require spree
//= require spree/frontend/cart
```

Note that I'm using Spree 3.0.0 in a Rails 4.2.0 app.